# how to configure alerts from log4j log for JON Agent for the scripts

Tags: log4j, rhq

I have an script running which generates log4j logs how can I configure for the alerts.

I am able to do it through JBoss but need to do it with JBoss server

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what you're trying to achieve. To start with, what do mean "JBoss" as opposed to "JBoss server"?

Comment: using JBoss I get server logs but I don't want it from the server log. I want to track it log4j .